How to add new consensus protocol for the Ethereum Quorum?
I am interested in adding a custom consensus protocol to Ethereum Quorum.
I would like to know if it's feasible to integrate my own custom consensus protocol into Quorum.
If adding a custom consensus protocol to Quorum is not practical, could you suggest alternative blockchain platforms that are more accommodating for custom consensus implementations?
Thank you
